# Checking if the elements of one array are the squared numbers of another one

Tags: java, algorithm

my fellow coders!

This is the problem I'm currently trying to solve. We've got 2 arrays, let's say:

```
a = new int[] {11, 12, 13, 14};
b = new int[] {121, 144, 169, 200};
```

My task is to compare 2 arrays and check whether 121 is 11 squared; 144 is 12 squared; etc.
That's my pseudocode:

1. for each int in the array a and for each int in the array b,
2. check if int i in a == int j in b multiplied by itself, then return true.
3. otherwise, return false.

My code:

```
public static boolean squared(int[] a, int[] b) {
for (int i : a)
  for (int j : b)
  if (b[j] == a[i]*a[i])
  return true;
  return false;
  } 
}
```

This algorithm logic seems fair to me; however, it fails to pass the test (I'm solving it online). Since I'm a newby, I wonder what would the more experienced programmers say, why does it not pass the test? What must be changed in pseudocode and in code itself, so that it outputs true if 121 = 11*11 and false for 200 = 14*14? 
Thanks in advance.

UPD.:Thank you everyone! The problem is solved. I agree I've made a logical mistake which looked obvious to the seasoned coders; though I see my question downvoted, it really took me a long time to figure the error out and I believe it was worth asking (to me).

Comment: In the code, `i` is a value from the `a` array not an index the same is true for `j`

Comment: Thank you, Andrew, now I see where I was wrong.

Comment: I'm sure you can solve this yourself. What happens if you print out the elements just before the comparison?

Comment: It is a task from codewars.com, so it is supposed to pass the test, and it's stated that it fails. Now, after Titus comment, I think I understand what was wrong and gonna fix it.

Comment: Your pseudo code formulation is misleading you. While I would say it is correct it is hard to translate 1:1 to actual code. As this seems to be s.th. like a homework I just give you a hint. Try to figure out what the difference is between your pseudo code statement to iterate over the array values simultaneously and your implementation iterating over the indices in nested loops.

Comment: I agree with you, Christian. My idea was to compare each element at index [j] with each one at index [i], and like people are hinting, that is not the same as `j` and `i`, and the nested for-each loops which I resorted to just to keep it short as possible, wasn't the best idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `a` and `b` have the same size and assuming you are using Java 8, you could just do this:

```
return (IntStream.range(0, a.length).filter(i->a[i]*a[i]!=b[i]).count())==0;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you @joel314! It helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your using an enhanced `for` loop with an array of integer.

In this situation, for `a = new int[] {11, 12, 13, 14}`, `a[i]` within the first loop represents `a[11]` and will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

You should replace

`for (int i : a)`

with

`for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++)`